# how to combine these two results as one in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have a query like this,

```
SELECT b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id, 
COUNT(DISTINCT a.file_id) AS sharedFiles  
FROM email_history a, users b  
WHERE a.email_receiver_id = b.user_id 
AND a.email_sender_id= 20  
GROUP BY b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id  
UNION  
SELECT b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id, 
COUNT(DISTINCT a.file_id) AS sharedFiles  
FROM email_history a, users b  
WHERE a.email_sender_id = b.user_id  
AND a.email_receiver_id= 20  
GROUP BY b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id;
```

Its ouput is -

```
user_id  first_name  last_name  email_id                   sharedFiles  
17       Mohan       Sharma     mohan.guptademo@gmail.com  2            
17       Mohan       Sharma     mohan.guptademo@gmail.com  1
```

Its showing two different records. but i want output like this -

```
user_id  first_name  last_name  email_id                   sharedFiles  
17       Mohan       Sharma     mohan.guptademo@gmail.com  3
```

I am new in mysql, so please help me how to get this output.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id, SUM(sharedFiles)as sharedFiles
FROM(
SELECT b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id, 
COUNT(DISTINCT a.file_id) AS sharedFiles  
FROM email_history a, users b  
WHERE a.email_receiver_id = b.user_id 
AND a.email_sender_id= 20  
GROUP BY b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id  
UNION  
SELECT b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id, 
COUNT(DISTINCT a.file_id) AS sharedFiles  
FROM email_history a, users b  
WHERE a.email_sender_id = b.user_id  
AND a.email_receiver_id= 20  
GROUP BY b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id)x
GROUP BY b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your query as a sub query allows for additional grouping and summartion. Look at the following query:

```
SELECT (b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id, SUM(b.sharedFiles) 
FROM (
    SELECT b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id, COUNT(DISTINCT a.file_id) AS sharedFiles  
    FROM email_history a, users b  
    WHERE a.email_receiver_id = b.user_id 
    AND a.email_sender_id= 20  
    GROUP BY b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id  UNION  
    UNION
    SELECT b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id, COUNT(DISTINCT a.file_id) AS sharedFiles  
    FROM email_history a, users b  
    WHERE a.email_sender_id = b.user_id  
    AND a.email_receiver_id= 20  
    GROUP BY b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id;
) AS b
GROUP BY b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id
```

Comment: My bad, give me a second to revise my answer

Answer (score 1):

The general solution for managing results of an UNION would be to place it in a subquery and do grouping in external function like this:

```
SELECT t.user_id, t.first_name, t.last_name, t.email_id, SUM(t.sharedFiles)
FROM 
(SELECT b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id,
COUNT(DISTINCT a.file_id) AS sharedFiles  
FROM email_history a, users b  
WHERE a.email_receiver_id = b.user_id 
AND a.email_sender_id= 20    
UNION  
SELECT b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id, 
COUNT(DISTINCT a.file_id) AS sharedFiles  
FROM email_history a, users b  
WHERE a.email_sender_id = b.user_id  
AND a.email_receiver_id=20) t 
GROUP BY t.user_id;
```

However, it seems like your precise request can be put on a single query with an OR.

```
SELECT b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id, 
COUNT(DISTINCT a.file_id) AS sharedFiles  
FROM email_history a, users b  
WHERE (a.email_receiver_id = b.user_id 
AND a.email_sender_id= 20) OR (a.email_sender_id = b.user_id  
AND a.email_receiver_id= 20) 
GROUP BY b.user_id,b.first_name, b.last_name, b.email_id
```